# How exactly does XNA's SpriteBatch work?

Tags: xna, spritebatch

To be more precise, if I needed to recreate this functionality from scratch in another API (e.g. in OpenGL) what would it need to be capable of doing?

I do have a general idea of some of the steps, such as how it prepares an orthographic projection matrix and creates a quad for each draw call.

I'm not too familiar, however, with the batching process itself. Are all quads stored in the same vertex buffer? Does it need an index buffer? How are different textures handled?

If possible I'd be grateful if you could guide me through the process from when SpriteBatch.Begin() is called until SpriteBatch.End(), at least when using the default Deferred mode.

Comment: Have a look at how it is implemented in MonoGame via OpenGL:

https://github.com/mono/MonoGame/blob/master/MonoGame.Framework/Graphics/SpriteBatch.cs

Comment: Did you try to use DotPeek or Reflector on Microsoft.Xna.Graphics (I am not suggesting to do anything illegal though :)?

Comment: Thanks for the link. And that thought did cross me (I even have dotPeek here at hand), but I figured it might be a better idea to ask for a general description from someone who might have already done that before and knows the procedure by memory. That way the answer would be preserved here and available to other people. In the case noone provides such a description, I'll do the analysis myself and post an answer to my own question, but I'll wait a bit more for now.

Comment: Yeah, that's the reason I used a comment. I think Andrew Russell might be a good person to answer this question. He is active in this community and is working on ExEn which is an alternative to MonoGame: http://andrewrussell.net/exen/.

Comment: Yeah, this is the sort of question that Andrew Russel (or Shawn Hargreaves back at the XNA forum) would usually be able provide a lot of insight into.

Comment: Also, the shader code for the 3.1(?) sprite batch is available on the AppHub if you need to see the GPU side of the CPU SpriteBatch http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/utility/spritebatch_shader

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I have sort of replicated the behaviour of SpriteBatch in deferred mode for a cross-platform engine I'm working on, so here are the steps I have reverse engineered so far:

1. **SpriteBatch constructor:** creates a `DynamicIndexBuffer`, `DynamicVertexBuffer` and array of `VertexPositionColorTexture` of fixed size (in this case, the maximum batch size - 2048 for sprites and 8192 for vertices).

   - The index buffer is filled with the vertex indices of the quads that will be drawn (0-1-2, 0-2-3, 4-5-6, 4-6-7 and so on).
   - An internal array of `SpriteInfo` structs is created, too. This will store temporal sprite settings to be used when batching.
2. **SpriteBatch.Begin:** internally stores the values of `BlendState`, `SamplerState`, etc. specified and checks if it has been called twice without a `SpriteBatch.End` in between.
3. **SpriteBatch.Draw:** takes all the sprite info (texture, position, color) and copies it to a `SpriteInfo`. If the max batch size is reached, the entire batch is drawn to make room for new sprites.

   - `SpriteBatch.DrawString` just issues a `Draw` for each character of the string, taking into account kerning and spacing.
4. **SpriteBatch.End:** does the following operations:

   - Sets the render states specified in `Begin`.
   - Creates the orthographic projection matrix.
   - Applies the `SpriteBatch` shader.
   - Binds the `DynamicVertexBuffer` and `DynamicIndexBuffer`.
   - Performs the following batching operation:

   ```cs
       startingOffset = 0;
       currentTexture, oldTexture = null;

       // Iterate through all sprites
       foreach SpriteInfo in SpriteBuffer
       {
           // Store sprite index and texture
           spriteIndex = SpriteBuffer.IndexOf(SpriteInfo);
           currentTexture = SpriteInfo.Texture;

           // Issue draw call if batch count > 0 and there is a texture change
           if (currentTexture != oldTexture)
           {
               if (spriteIndex > startingOffset)
               {
                   RenderBatch(oldTexture, SpriteBuffer, startingOffset,
                               spriteIndex - startingOffset);
               }
               startingOffset = spriteIndex;
               oldTexture = currentTexture;
           }
       }

       // Draw remaining batch and clear the sprite data
       RenderBatch(currentTexture, SpriteBuffer, startingOffset,
                   SpriteBuffer.Count - startingOffset);
       SpriteBuffer.Clear();
   ```
5. **SpriteBatch.RenderBatch:** executes the following operations for each of the `SpriteInfo` in the batch:

   - Takes the position of the sprite and calculates the final position of the four vertices according to the origin and size. Applies existing rotation.
   - Calculates the UV coordinates and applies specified `SpriteEffects` to them.
   - Copies the sprite color.
   - These values are then stored in the array of `VertexPositionColorTexture` elements previously created. When all sprites have been calculated, `SetData` is called on the `DynamicVertexBuffer` and a `DrawIndexedPrimitives` call is issued.
   - The vertex shader only performs a tranform operation, and the pixel shader applies the tinting on the color fetched from the texture.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, thanks a lot! Took me a bit to absorb all of that, but I think I finally got all the details. One that caught my attention and I wasn't entirely aware of before is that even in deferred mode, if I can somehow sort my SpriteBatch.Draw calls by Texture (i.e. if I don't care about the order of these calls) it will reduce the number of RenderBatch operations, and probably speed up the rendering.

Comment: By the way, I can't seem to find in the documentation - what's the limit of Draw calls you can make before the buffer gets full? And does calling DrawText fill that buffer by the entire amount of characters in the string?

Comment: Impressive! How will your engine compare to ExEn and MonoGame? Will it require MonoTouch and MonoAndroid as well? Thanks.

Comment: @DavidGouveia: 2048 sprites is the max batch size - edited the answer and added it for convenience. Yes, sorting by texture and letting the z-buffer take care of sprite ordering would use the minimum draw calls. If you need it, try implementing `SpriteSortMode.Texture` to draw in whatever order you want and let the `SpriteBatch` do the sorting.

Comment: @Den: ExEn and MonoGame are lower-level APIs that allow XNA code run in non-Windows platform. The project I'm working on is a component-based engine purely written in C#, but we need a very thin layer to provide access to system APIs (that's where I'm working on). We just chose to reimplement `SpriteBatch` for convenience. And yes, it requires MonoTouch/MonoDroid since it's all C#!

Comment: Would SortMode.Immediate make it actually draw at SpriteBatch.Draw and not at SpriteBatch.End?

Comment: @ClassicThunder: yes, that's the behaviour of `SpriteSortMode.Immediate`.

Comment: Are you sure it draws immediately when it hits the max batch size? The existence of `SpriteSortMode.BackToFront` implies that it accumulates everything - I could be wrong though; I haven't actually inspected it.

Answer (score 14):

Just want to point out that the XNA SpriteBatch code has been ported to DirectX and released as OSS by a previous member of the XNA team. So if you want to see exactly how it works in XNA, the latest version of the XNA SpriteBatch as native C++ can be found [on this GitHub repo](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/): [`.h`](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/blob/master/Inc/SpriteBatch.h) & [`.cpp`](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/blob/master/Src/SpriteBatch.cpp)

A [DirectX12 version](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK12/) is also available: [`.h`](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK12/blob/master/Inc/SpriteBatch.h) & [`.cpp`](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK12/blob/master/Src/SpriteBatch.cpp)

Comment: +1 for "code I'll never use but is interesting to skim over"

Comment: The latest version of the XNA SpriteBatch as native C++ can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/) [h](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/blob/master/Inc/SpriteBatch.h) / [cpp](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/blob/master/Src/SpriteBatch.cpp). As a bonus, a DirectX12 version is also [available](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK12/) [h](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK12/blob/master/Inc/SpriteBatch.h) / [cpp](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK12/blob/master/Src/SpriteBatch.cpp)